# submit form data and files using phonegap?

Tags: php, mysql, json, file-upload, cordova

I have created simple html form that contains text inputs, text area , files such as uploading images ..

how could I submit this form data when turning it into phone gap application that contains user registration to his data and photo and cv document?

when submitting data it should be sent to php page where mysql insert will held?

I have tried the serialize method face problems in getting data in th php page

also couldn't find the way to upload file and images??

any help???

Comment: you need to paste some relevant code

Comment: where you submit the data ....external database or else?

Comment: I want to submit data to external mysql database uploaded on server

Comment: see this post for more information 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634967/form-with-data-and-image-submission-using-phonegap

Answer (score 2):

```
  <script>
```

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
```

console.log("Hello ");
    $("#button").click(function(evt){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var sendData = { "name": name, "message": message };

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/webs/main/ajax/process.php",
    data: sendData,
    success: function(data) {
        log.console(data);
         $("#info").html(data);

    }

});

 alert("Hello ");
 alert($("#test").val());
 alert($("#name").val());
 alert($("#message").val());
 return false;
```

});
  }

Comment: I see ..ok How to upload Image?

Answer (score 1):

```
Upload image using phonegap
============================

function uploadImage(){
       //Using Camera
       navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFailcapturePhoto, { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 
        //Using library            
       navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFailcapturePhoto, { quality: 50,destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});    
}

function onFailcapturePhoto(message) {    
   console.log("Message = " + message);
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
  var imagefile = imageURI; 
  $('#vImage').attr('src', imagefile);
/* Image Upload Start */
var ft = new FileTransfer();                     
var options = new FileUploadOptions();                      
options.fileKey="vImage1";                      
options.fileName=imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";                       
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;                       
ft.upload(imagefile, your_service_url, win, fail, options);   
}

function win(r) {
  console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
   console.log("Response = " + r.response);
   //alert($.parseJSON(r.response))    
}

function fail(error) {
   console.log("Response = " +  error.code);
} 
On your php file 
=================
 file_put_contents("file.txt", print_r($_FILES, true));
 Post Form data and Image together 
 ================================ 
// Here first submit your form input data after successfully submit upload image call

$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
if(event.handled !== true)
{
    var ajax_call = serviceURL; 
    var str = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_call,
        data: str,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){              
            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                // after success submit data
                if(response){
                    var imagefile = $('#vImage').attr('src');
                    /* Image Upload Start */    
                    var ft = new FileTransfer();                     
                    var options = new FileUploadOptions();                      
                    options.fileKey="vImage1";                      
                    options.fileName=imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
                    options.mimeType="image/png"; 
                    var params = new Object();
                    params.value1 = "test";
                    params.value2 = "param";                       
                    options.params = params;
                    options.chunkedMode = false;                       
                    ft.upload(imagefile, your_service_url, win, fail, options);

                  }                                     
            });
        }
    });
    event.handled = true;
}
return false;
})
```

Comment: how could I integrate this code with the other form elements (such as name , gender, height, ...ect) to submit all together using ajax or json to and external php page on my server where the insert mysql query will happen?

Comment: should I include the function uploadImage() or just start from the submit event?

Comment: how the html file structure would be?? I have tried it but nothing happens?