# form with data and image submission using phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I'm using phonegap, html, ajax, jquery , mysql, and php.

In my Phonagep Application I have form that contain username, password, userphoto.

I want to submit this form from the html page. lets say register.html

form data should be sent to php page that is uploaded on my server in a folder named services lets say the path is "http://www.example.com/services/register.php".

this page should handle mysql insert process to a database that is also uploaded on the same server.

on this server I have also folder named images where user image should be uploaded and its full bath should be inserted in the mysql database.

I have tried using ajax to post user name and passowrd to this page and inserted data succssfully. but I face problem with the data when using serialize().

also I can't upload the image using ajax?

I used this code .. I get response for username and password without sending the image path but nothing happens when sending the image path

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic Upload</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


function sub(e){

var ft = new FileTransfer();   
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="myImg";
options.fileName=$('#myImg').val();
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
options.mimeType="image/png"; 
options.chunkedMode = false;
var PATH = options.fileName;

var form_data= new Object();
form_data['user_name']= 'User';
form_data['password']= '1234';
form_data['user_image_path']= PATH;

var url = "http://localhost/stacktest/register.php"; 
$.getJSON(""+url+"?callback=?"+"&form_data="+JSON.stringify(form_data),
    function (response) {
        try {
            // Get Your Response
            alert(response);
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
   }
);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="registerForm" onsubmit="sub(this.value);">

    <input type="file" name="myImg" id="myImg" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP Webservice with Json to perform following task

Access Web Service Like :-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>  
var PATH = 'Image Path';
var form_data= new Object();
form_data['user_name']= 'User';
form_data['password']= '1234';
form_data['user_image_path']= PATH;

var url = "http://localhost/stacktest/register.php";
$.getJSON(""+url+"?callback=?"+"&form_data="+JSON.stringify(form_data),
    function (response) {
        try {
            // Get Your Response
            alert(response);
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
   }
);
</script>
```

Create PHP Webservice(register.php) like :-

```
<?php
$form_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET["form_data"]));
$user_name = $form_data->user_name;
$password = $form_data->password;
$user_image_path = $form_data->user_image_path;

//Perform Your Task like Insert into Database etc

$res= 'Your Response which you want to return'; 
echo $_GET["callback"].'('.json_encode($res).')';
```

Comment: thanks for edit :)

what is the image path? 


should I use phonegap filetransfer or not?

Comment: image path is your file url which you want to upload if you don't know about the image url. you can use phonegap file transfer instead of curl to download.

Comment: my Image should be chosen from user device to be uploaded to a folser on the server http://www.example.com/Images/

I used input file in the html 

<input type="file" name="myImg" id="myImg" />

Comment: could you please give me working example or demo for the work?

Comment: you should use then phonegap file transfer

Comment: I used your code but I get no response from the php page, why?

Comment: Hi @Ala: I have updated the code above and tested from my side. It is working as Expected.

Comment: I used this code .. I get response for username and password without sending the image path but nothing happens when sending the image path?? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think your path is incorrect because webservice can't access the path of your file which scope is within your app. to upload your file read more about [Cordova File Transfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

**[Update]**

You can download the working project from [GitHub](https://github.com/ShashiBadhuk/PhonegapFileUpload)

Read [PhonegapFileUpload Blog](http://shashibadhuk.blogspot.in/2014/04/uploading-image-from-phonegap-mobile.html)

Comment: I used alert to chech the path and the image name its like this before sending to the php side :  C:\fakepath\image.jpg

is this wrong path?

Comment: yes because the path `C:\fakepath\image.jpg` is respective to your Device and it is not accessible by the Webservice. you should use the file path like `www.some_domain.com/fakepath/image.jpg`, I think it would work as you expected.

Comment: ok how could I do this during the image upload process??

the image will be uploaded from my device to a folder in my server

Comment: If you don't need to store image on your server than save the path of image in database. each time you pick the path through webservice and access the image from the device rather than your server.